# How not to display Django foreign key object source in table

Tags: django

I want to display date in table which is foreign key in this case and when I do this as result I see the date with information that it is object of different table. Which I don't want. 
I would appreciate help with this.

[image]

```
class Factclaimcases(models.Model):
    idfactclaimcase = models.IntegerField(db_column='IdFactClaimCase', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    idtechnican = models.ForeignKey(Dimtechnican, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='IdTechnican')  # Field name made lowercase.
    thedate = models.ForeignKey(Dimdate, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='TheDate')  # Field name made lowercase.
    description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    manufacturedef = models.TextField(db_column='ManufactureDef', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.
    doc = models.BinaryField(db_column='Doc', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

```
<div class="container">
  <table>
    {% for item in query_results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.idfactclaimcase }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.thedate }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```

```
def index(request):
    query_results = Factclaimcases.objects.all()
    context = {
        'query_results': query_results,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

```
class Dimdate(models.Model):
    thedate = models.DateField(db_column='TheDate', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    theday = models.IntegerField(db_column='TheDay', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    thedayname = models.CharField(db_column='TheDayName', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    theweek = models.IntegerField(db_column='TheWeek', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    theisoweek = models.IntegerField(db_column='TheISOWeek', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    thedayofweek = models.IntegerField(db_column='TheDayOfWeek', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    themonth = models.IntegerField(db_column='TheMonth', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    themonthname = models.CharField(db_column='TheMonthName', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    thequarter = models.IntegerField(db_column='TheQuarter', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    theyear = models.IntegerField(db_column='TheYear', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    thefirstofmonth = models.DateField(db_column='TheFirstOfMonth', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    thelastofyear = models.DateField(db_column='TheLastOfYear', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    thedayofyear = models.IntegerField(db_column='TheDayOfYear', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Comment: Can you share the `Dimdate` model?

Comment: At the bottom of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You render it by accessing the field you want to render, so:

```
<div class="container">
  <table>
    {% for item in query_results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.idfactclaimcase }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.thedate.thedate }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```

You can use the [**`|date`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) to specify how to render the date, for example:

```
<div class="container">
  <table>
    {% for item in query_results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.idfactclaimcase }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.thedate.thedate|date:"Y-m-d" }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```

In your view, you can select the `Dimdate` columns in the same query with [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
def index(request):
    query_results = Factclaimcases.objects.select_related('thedate')
    context = {
        'query_results': query_results,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you. Great answer.